# sort array values ​with integers above the other data types

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this :

`$arr = [456, 8, 1, -9, 'string', true, 0, -65, -162]`

I want to sort array values descending and also I want integer values to be above the other value types,

I've tried with `rsort($arr)` , then i do `var_dump` but the result is

```
array (size=9)
0 => int 456
1 => int 8
2 => int 1
3 => string 'string' (length=6)
4 => int -9
5 => boolean true
6 => int 0
7 => int -65
8 => int -162
```

how do make that array sorted with integer above the other data type?

exemple:

`$arr = [456, 8, 1, 0, -9,-65, -162, 'string', true]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `usort` with a custom sort function which checks for integers before comparing values:

```
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    if (is_integer($a) && !is_integer($b)) return -1;
    elseif (!is_integer($a) && is_integer($b)) return 1;
    else return $b <=> $a;
});
var_dump($arr);
```

Output:

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  int(456)
  [1]=>
  int(8)
  [2]=>
  int(1)
  [3]=>
  int(0)
  [4]=>
  int(-9)
  [5]=>
  int(-65)
  [6]=>
  int(-162)
  [7]=>
  string(6) "string"
  [8]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/HKuqc)